# Elementary physics question...requires calculus?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A 2500.0kg car is going at a constant velocity of 14.0 m/s and hits the breaks to stop. It skids 25m. What is the coefficient of friction of the tires to the ground?

So I have acceleration = -4.0 m/s^2
Normal force = 24525 N

I got Fnet = -100,000 N

And I don't know what to do now because normally I take the difference of Fnet between the amount of force applied and the amount of force that worked. But then what should have happened was that the brakes were hit and the car immediately stops but then distance = 0 and I can't divide by 0. So I'm probably forgetting something...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient of friction is simply defined as the ratio of the frictional force between the object and the surface to the normal force pressing the object and the surface toegether:

$$ \mu := \frac{F_f}{F_N} $$.

In your specific problem, the net force is equal to just force-friction, and by Newton's 2nd law equal to mass times acceleration, so $F_f = ma$. Since the surface is horizontal, the normal force has the same magnitude as the force of gravity (weight), so $F_N = mg$. Then,

$$\mu_k = \frac{ma}{mg} = \frac{a}{g}.$$

Using familiar equations for constant acceleration, the acceleration of an object which travels a distance $d$ braking from an initial speed $v_0$ to rest is $a=\frac{v_0^2}{2d}$. Hence,

$$\mu_k = \frac{ma}{mg} = \frac{v_0^2}{2gd} = 0.4 $$

Note in particular that the mass of the car turned out to be completely irrelevant information; we only needed the initial velocity and the distance traveled.

Answer (score -1):

Remember you can rearrange equations like the one for force of friction.
Actually you did all the work now it is just:

Fnorm * u = Fnet ... or ... u = Fnet/Fnorm

100000(N)/24525(N) ~= 4

Just to double check, cause you took all the work from me.
We know the integration of force over time gives us momentum, that is:

2500(kg)*14(m/s)=35000(kg*m/s)

So using your "Fnet" how much time would it take to come to a stop?

Fnet * T = P

Sorry, I learned P is Momentum, that is...

100000(N)*T(s)=35000(kg*m/s)

Now Solve for T:

[35000(kg*m/s)]/[100000(N)]=0.35(s)

and assuming constant smooth acceleration we can say the average velocity is half the starting.

7(m/s)*3.5(s)=2.45(m)

What 2.45(m)!!! um, that's not right, some number needs double checking...
sorry, best of luck to you.